# php Foreach loop group data

Tags: php, foreach

I need help for each loop that I would like to find the data from mysqldbx with find if data have parent category first and grouping the data with them parent and echo them out with for each loop maybe it looks like this below :

start for each loop

- show 1st category all row(only include category1)
- show 2st category 2 for the next also all row (only category 2)
- show 5 category 5 ,this also all row (only category 5) ,finish if no data

  ```
  <tr><td>row=id</td> <td>row=nama</td> <td>row=category1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row=id</td> <td>row=nama</td> <td>row=category2</td></tr> 
  <tr><td>row=id</td> <td>row=nama</td> <td>row=category5</td></tr>
  ```

end theforeach loop

Example data on table

```
id=1,name=data1,category=1

id=2, name=data2,category=1

id=3, name=data3,category=5

id=4, name=data4,category=2

id=5, name=data5,category=5

id=6, name=data6,category=2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `SQL query` for this table and you can order by category,
i.e.

```
select * from your_table order by category
```

Then you have to do nothing with `foreach loop`

Comment: actually its just database manipulate it doesnt work to put data on grid partition group like tr td /td /tr and next group to tr td /tr /td,its similiar for dynamic dropdown button but its only one level,  anyways thanks for your advice